# MySQL / InnoDB / Incorrect key file for table Error

Tags: mysql, innodb

I keep seeing this pop up in my logs every few hours.

```
Trying to get property of non-object -- Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_ad2_2.MYI'; try to repair it
```

I ran mysqlcheck on all tables, but I still get it. Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the key file error you're getting is on a temporary table or a table being rebuilt.  You might check your processlist to see if you have some very large query running that is trying to do a create temporary table select * from something;

Since it is a /tmp table, it should be removed when the thread that created it terminates.  When the logs pop up, is it the same filename?  or a different filename?  Is it possible that /tmp is not set chmod 1777 ?  or are there files there that mysql created that don't have the correct uid:gid?

Comment: I suspected it was a temp table, but I just couldn't figure out why. /tmp/ is 777. Is it possible this is an innodb bug?

Comment: .MYI is a MyISAM file.  I'm wondering if you have something running mysqlcheck on a cron job, and it just happens to hit an old tmp file that was abandoned.  What is the date on that file, is it recent?